# Evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x) dx$ where $g(x) = \int_{0}^x f(t) dt$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function such that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) dt = 0$. Define $g(x) = \int_{0}^x f(t) dt$. Evaluate

> $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x) dx$$

I hope the integral is equal to zero. I have the following:
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x) dx\\
=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\int_{0}^x f(t) dt\right) dx\\
=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(-\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)xdx + x\int_{0}^x f(t)dt \Biggr|_{-\pi}^\pi\right)
\end{align}

But I am not sure how to proceed?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fubini's theorem? It immediately provides the answer, which is zero.

Comment: @Vik78 But the upper limit of my inner integral is $x$, not some number.

Comment: Set x equal to any number and apply Fubini's theorem. This shows that the function is zero no matter the choice of x.